# Sort by "Highest Rated" with thumbs up/down votes

Tags: user-expectation

My website has lists of images and a simple rating system that uses thumbs up and thumbs down votes. Now I want to be able to sort the list page by "Highest Rated" (as well as "Lowest Rated"). However, I don't know the "expected" way to do this as there are multiple ways:

**1. Sort by the number of upvotes**

This satisfies the "highest rated" aspect, an image will 1,000 upvotes is higher rated than an image with 5 upvotes. However, what if that same image has 10,000 downvotes. Is it really higher rated than an image with 5 upvotes 0 downvotes?

**2. Sort by ratio of upvotes**

So an image with 1,000 and 10,000 downvotes will only have a upvote ratio of 1:10 or 0.1, while an image with 5 upvotes and 3 downvotes will have a ratio of 1.6, thus it will take into account both ratings to give a more accurate depiction of how it was rated. However, that mean an image with 1 upvote and 0 downvotes will be higher rated than one with 1,000 up and 1,001 down, which at face value might look confusing.

**Which way of sorting ratings will make the most sense to the users?**

Comment: It sounds like you might have to create your own system of what is "the highest rated." In my opinion, I think that could be done by accounting for the number of upvotes vs downvotes vs total. So for instance the 1,000 - 10,000 of 11,000 which really gives it a low rating (only 1K is positive, which means it is 9K in the red) VS 5 - 3 of 8 should ideally give it a good rating because it IS in the positive. But it should rank lower than something that got, say 1,000 - 200 of 1200. I guess what I'm trying to say is that 9K negative is still negative, which is a pretty low rating.

Comment: @Majo0od Hmm, that is a good point. Perhaps I could do something like take the ratio I mentioned in #2 and then use the total votes # as some sort of multiplier. So that 9K negative carries more weight than 3 negative. Although that might be so complicated users will not understand it.

Comment: I don't think so. You're not showing the math, you're just showing the list.

Comment: Showing the list with your suggestion will be enough and users will just click on what is recommended.

Comment: @Majo0od I actually found a duplicate now with an answer saying to do pretty much that so I think thats the way! Thanks

Comment: Just saw that. Glad at least it is resolved for you :)